# why is a div element pushed under an anchor when an inner div contains text that begins to wrap?

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a list item containing a "grab handle" anchor and a div which contains an inner div containing text. When the text in the inner div reaches the container width and begins to wrap the outer div is forced below the anchor. I would like it that no matter how much text there is the outer div is never forced below the anchor and instead the text just wraps within the space.

I have a jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tazmaniax/qepwV/) with two list items with varying amounts of text to demonstrate.

In the screenshot from the jsFiddle below you can see with first list item the "drag handle" anchor is on its own line with the rest of the details pushed down because of the description text length

[image]

Here is my html:

```
<ul class="sortable">
    <li>
        <span class="dragHandle"></span>
        <div class="itemContentContainer">
            <a href="/events/7708">Ticket Admin</a>
            <div>Every week there will be one shift of 2 people to help count the cash and sort the ticket orders</div>
            <div>Still needed: 16&nbsp;&nbsp;Helping: 0</div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="dragHandle"></span>
        <div class="itemContentContainer">
            <a href="/events/7309">Decorations - Nursery PM, Rbw B, Red</a>
            <div>Decorate the School grounds with bunting etc that you have made.</div>
            <div>Still needed: 10&nbsp;&nbsp;Helping: 0</div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and CSS

```
ul.sortable {
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
    margin: 1em -19px 0;
    list-style: none;
}

ul.sortable > li:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

ul.sortable > li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 0 0 0 19px;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

li {
    line-height: 20px;
}

ul.sortable .dragHandle {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: url('http://service.ptasocial.com/public/img/reorder-lines.png') no-repeat left center;
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em;
    margin-right: 1em;
    background-size: 100%;
}

ul.sortable .itemContentContainer {
    padding: 0.75em 0;
    display: inline-block;
}

a {
    color: #c63d13;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/qepwV/18/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used `inline-block`. It is not a good practice. The best one is to use `position`ing and position the drag handler, and give the parent `div` some left padding.

So the code for your CSS would be:

```
ul.sortable .dragHandle {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 15px;
    z-index: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: url('http://service.ptasocial.com/public/img/reorder-lines.png') no-repeat left center;
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em;
    margin-right: 1em;
    background-size: 100%;
}

ul.sortable .itemContentContainer {
    padding: 0.75em 0 0.75em 35px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

#### Preview

[image]

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/qepwV/7/

Comment: `You have used inline-block. It is not a good practice` - That's like saying sleeping isn't good practice. You shouldn't do it at work, but I'm sure you do sleep once in a while.